# How to Delete All App Data for Testing APK

Tags: android

I've been pulling my hair out trying to finalize testing on an Android app that will not release data from the previously installed version. I'm using a Nexus 7 and Samsung Galaxy, and no matter what I do — clear the app cache, clear the app data, force quit the app, uninstall the app — it continues to load the new version with the old problems in place, and I know they've been corrected. The way I know this is that I did a complete wipe and factory reset of the Nexus, used a new Gmail account specifically for this experiment, and the app loaded as it should. But once I go back and try my admin Gmail account, it goes back to loading old data again.

Is there a way to COMPLETELY delete old data, so that each test of the APK is as if it was by a first time user? The Beta Test area I'm using in Google Dev is no help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your app upload or store anything in the cloud ? The fact that the data seems to be associated with a Gmail account seems to indicate this. Also: is sync / auto-backup turned on for app data ? (Check in device settings > sync) Google automatically backs up app data if this is enabled and restores it on app reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this app also a pre-intall app on the device? uninstalling the apk should clear all prior data I'm surprised even that didn't work for you.